# Iteration through defines

Tags: c, dynamic, c-preprocessor

I'm working in a **C** program and I came across a problem. I have this

```
#define NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS 5 

#define NAME_OPTION1 "Partida Rapida"
#define NAME_OPTION2 "Elige Nivel"
#define NAME_OPTION3 "Ranking"
#define NAME_OPTION4 "Creditos"
#define NAME_OPTION5 "Exit"


for (iterator = 1; iterator <= NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS; iterator++){

    menu_options[iterator-1]= NAME_OPTION + iterator
}
```

I want that "NAME_OPTION + iterator" takes the value of the corresponding `#define.` For example if the variable "iterator" is equal to one, I want `menu_options[iterator-1]` to take the value of `NAME_OPTION1`, which is "Partida Rapida".

How can I get this?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you can't. `#define` macros are handled by the C Preprocessor and do *textual substitution* wherever that macro appears in the code. The macro `NAME_OPTION` has not been defined, so the compiler should complain. C does not allow appending numbers onto strings, or especially onto symbols like `NAME_OPTION.` Use an array of `const char*`, which you can then refer to with your iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use defines as this, you can do:

```
const char *menu_options[5] = {
   "Partida Rapida",
   "Elige Nivel",
   "Ranking",
   "Creditos",
   "Exit"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use #define macro, you just tell preprocessor to replace every occurence of defined word by something else before the code is compiled into machine code. 
In this case NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS will be replaced by 5, but there's no occurence of NAME_OPTION*, so nothing will be replaced and you'll probably get an error while preprocessing.

Piere's solutions shows how to do it, but I highly doubt that there's an iterator over char *array, so you have to iterate over given array using an integer index.

Comment: I appreciate all your answers but i could not understand what you mean when you say "I highly doubt that there's an iterator over char *array, so you have to iterate over give array with an integer index"

Comment: Iterator is a class you can use to "iterate" over given STL container (in c++). When you're iterating with iterator, the iterator represents  exactly one object from given container. So, if you do something like this: container.begin(), it will return an object of type iterator and that object represent the first item in given container. 
I don't want to confuse you, so if you don't know the stuff I described above(or you're trying to iterate over basic array). use just for loop as you wrote above. By iterator I meant an iterator class, not integer index. I hope it's clear now